# Largest possible value of $x$

Tags: inequality

Problem:

> Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers satisfying $\frac{x^2y^2 - 1}{2y-1}=3x.$ Find the largest possible value of $x.$

How would I do this? Would I multiply each side by $2y-1$?

Comment: That might be a good start. Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Never heard of them

Comment: Okay, then a direct method is called for. The answer by dxiv looks good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: eliminate the denominator and consider it as a quadratic equation in $y\,$: $$x^2 \cdot y^2 - 6x \cdot y +3x -1 = 0$$

For the quadratic to have real roots, its discriminant must be non-negative:

$$
\frac{1}{4} \Delta = 9 x^2 -x^2(3x -1) = x^2(10 - 3x) \ge 0
$$

Comment: +1 out of curiosity, do you think implicit differentiation could solve this problem?

Comment: @qbert Don't know that it would, since the maximum is attained on the boundary of the region (but, even if it did, it would be an overkill in a case like this one).

Comment: indeed, it is also difficult to tell when $x$ can be written as a function of $y$. Thanks!